# Operação com datas Python

Tags: python

Estou querendo calcular o valor a ser pago, levando em consideração as seguintes regras:

- atraso juro de 5% + 10
- pagamento adiantado tem desconto de 3%

o meu código está dando erro

```
import datetime
valor = float(input(' Valor do Boleto: '))
dia = int(input('Dia de Pagamento: '))
mes = int(input('Mês de Pagamento: '))
ano = int(input('Ano de Pagamento: '))
pagamento = datetime.date(day=dia, month=mes, year=ano)
dia = int(input('Dia de Vencimento: '))
mes = int(input('Mês de Vencimento: '))
ano = int(input('Ano de Vencimento: '))
Vencimento = datetime.date(day=dia, month=mes, year=ano)
dif = Vencimento - pagamento
if dif < 0:
    novo = valor + (valor * 5 / 100) + 10
else:
    novo = (valor * 97/100)
print(novo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz dessa forma!!

```
import datetime
valor = float(input(' Valor do Boleto: '))
dia = int(input('Dia de Pagamento: '))
mes = int(input('Mês de Pagamento: '))
ano = int(input('Ano de Pagamento: '))
pagamento = datetime.date(day=dia, month=mes, year=ano)
diav = int(input('Dia de Vencimento: '))
mesv = int(input('Mês de Vencimento: '))
anov = int(input('Ano de Vencimento: '))
Vencimento = datetime.date(day=diav, month=mesv, year=anov)
if pagamento < Vencimento:
    novo = valor + (valor * 5 / 100) + 10
else:
    novo = (valor * 97 / 100)
print(novo)
```